# TypeError running yolact's train.py

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to execute the yolact code :
https://github.com/dbolya/yolact
but I have this error when I run `train.py`:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Sylvain ARD/Dropbox/Documents Sylvain/travail avec Boubacar/yolact/yolact-master/yolact-master/train.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sylvain ARD/Dropbox/Documents Sylvain/travail avec Boubacar/yolact/yolact-master/yolact-master')
Scaling parameters by 0.12 to account for a batch size of 1.
Per-GPU batch size is less than the recommended limit for batch norm. Disabling batch norm.
loading annotations into memory...
Done (t=0.03s)
creating index...
index created!
loading annotations into memory...
Done (t=0.00s)
creating index...
index created!
Initializing weights...
Begin training!

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sylvain ARD\Dropbox\Documents Sylvain\travail avec Boubacar\yolact\yolact-master\yolact-master\train.py", line 505, in <module>
    train()

  File "C:\Users\Sylvain ARD\Dropbox\Documents Sylvain\travail avec Boubacar\yolact\yolact-master\yolact-master\train.py", line 271, in train
    for datum in data_loader:

  File "C:\Users\Sylvain ARD\.conda\envs\yolact\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 819, in __next__
    return self._process_data(data)

  File "C:\Users\Sylvain ARD\.conda\envs\yolact\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 846, in _process_data
    data.reraise()

  File "C:\Users\Sylvain ARD\.conda\envs\yolact\lib\site-packages\torch\_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)

TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'casting', 'from_', 'to', and 'i'
```

please help me
thank you
best regards

Comment: As can be seen, the __init__() func requires 4 positional arguments. Carefully read the accompanying documentation/README on how to execute the project.

Comment: I don't know what __init__ is it, this is not me that I call it but the code of github itself